# securing graylog2 http port from spam logs??

Tags: graylog2

I'm not really sure how to word the title. This is what i'm trying to do. I'm fairly new to graylog2. I have graylog2 installed to listen on a specific port number to listen for logs sent over the HTTP. So, how do i avoid someone from spamming my graylog server with fake log files?

Answer (score 1):

Currently graylog2 has no built-in capability to prevent that.
However, authenticated HTTP inputs have already been requested and we have an issue open to implement this: [Support authenticated HTTP GELF input](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/issues/335)

For now the only option would be to restrict access to the host/port using standard firewall techniques.